# Is it possible to use CONST or service global as parameter in annotation?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I'm trying to set a dynamic default value in doctrine ORM annotation for when I update my app.

Thus, instead of having

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", options={"default": "1.0"})
 */
private $version;
```

I would have something like :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", options={"default": "%version%"})
 */
private $version;
```

I declared a const `APP_VERSION` `App\Kernel` and then imported it in `services.yaml` under the name of `appVersion`.

Do you know if it's possible to use either the const in `App\Kernel` or the global in `services.yaml` as parameter in Doctrine ORM annotation?
Anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: Can APP_VERSION be an actual PHP constant? Perhaps defined in the Kernel class?  If so, private $version = Kernel::APP_VERSION might be all you need.  Otherwise, it might be best to use a factory to create the entity and have the factory set the version.

Comment: @Cerad it's not about defining the default value in PHP, but having the SQL default value set

Comment: Sure but if you set it in PHP then there is no need for a default SQL value.  It's also in keeping with the notion that Doctrine entities have no direct relationship to the database.  In any event, you can do mappings in PHP though it's unusual.  That would allow setting the version dynamically.  I don't know of any annotation based approach.  The config stuff is all Symfony while the mappings are Doctrine based.  Doctrine itself knows nothing of the Symfony config system.

Comment: I see, guess it won't be possible then. Thanks for the details @Cerad

Comment: according to https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.10/custom.html#constants you can use defined constants. you could also be able to create a new annotation that can be used in annotations that receives a parameter (the config variable name) and "replaces" it with the value ... that might be possible ... I'm not quite sure though.

Comment: to further extend my comment, I believe your annotation would be provided to the column metadata/mapping as-is, which might turn out to be a problem when the value is used. since it might be expected to be something it can't be, like the float in your example. if it was expected to be a string, you could implement `__toString` (which by the way "version" definitely should be, from an abstract standpoint, a version number is NOT a float!) and even then I'm not quite certain if it would work ...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable inside .env then give the default value in the constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->version = $_ENV["YOUR_VAR"];
}
```